# Scala Akka Play, Future doesn't return

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, future

I'm using Scala 2.10, Akka 2.1 and Play 2.1. When I send an http request to my backend, I `ask` one actor to compute something. The idea is to return the result of the calculation if it returns before a timeout, otherwise a different string. See code below.

```
val futureInt: Future[Int] = ask(testActor, Calculate(number.toInt)).mapTo[Int]
val timeoutFuture = play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout("Oops", 2.seconds)

Async {
  Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(futureInt, timeoutFuture)).map {
    case i: Int => Ok("Got result " + i)
    case t: String => Ok("timeout expired")
  }
}
```

The actor is as follows:

```
class TestActor() extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Calculate(tonumber: Int) =>
      for (a <- 1 to tonumber) {
        val c: Double = scala.math.pow(a, 2)
        println("a: " + a + ", c: " + c)
      }
      12345 // hardcoded value to return when the calculation finishes
    case _ =>
      println("bah")
  }
}
```

My problem is that even if the actor finishes before the timeout, nothing is "returned" by the Future and so the timeout always expires. What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

> Using ask will send a message to the receiving Actor as with tell, and the receiving actor must reply with sender ! reply in order to complete the returned Future with a value.

and

> **Warning**
>
> To complete the future with an exception you need send a Failure message to the sender. This is not done automatically when an actor throws an exception while processing a message.

So instead of "returning" like you would in a usual scala function, do something along the lines of

```
def receive = {
  case Calculate(tonumber: Int) =>
    ...
    sender ! 12345
  case _ =>
    sender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(new InvalidArgumentException)
}
```

Comment: hey Dylan, thanks for your reply. From the akka docs though, your suggestion only works if the actor has been invoked by another actor: "There are generally two ways of getting a reply from an Actor: the first is by a sent message (actor ! msg), which only works if the original sender was an Actor) and the second is through a Future."

Comment: nevermind. Your solution is the working one. I'm going to send a message to the akka team!

Comment: The ask pattern creates that necessary actor under the hood so indeed  your actor sends back the message to another actor. However, you as the caller receive the future as expected.